# Nested liquid custom tag blocks

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid

I'm having trouble with getting some nested liquid tags to compile if the outer tag contains multiple sibling liquid tags. This works:

```
{% container %}
  {% inner %}
    Stuff Goes in here
  {% endinner %}
{% endcontainer %}
```

but this doesn't

```
{% container %}
  {% inner %}
    Stuff Goes in here
  {% endinner %}
  {% inner %}
    Stuff Goes in here
  {% endinner %}
{% endcontainer %}
```

I get the following error:

```
Liquid Exception: Liquid syntax error (line 1): 'container' tag was never closed in /.../_posts/blah.markdown/#excerpt
Liquid Exception: Liquid syntax error (line 1): 'container' tag was never closed in _includes/head.html, included in _layouts/default.html
```

Notice that `#excerpt` in the first error? If I add an excerpt into the front matter. Everything works fine. My head.html include is the default one with a new jekyll site:

```
  <meta name="description" content="{% if page.excerpt %}{{ page.excerpt | strip_html | strip_newlines | truncate: 160 }}{% else %}{{ site.description }}{% endif %}">
```

Removing the if statement in the head will make the error go away too. I'm completely confused as to why having multiple siblings would cause this error. Here's my simplified plugin code:

```
module Jekyll
  class RenderContainer < Liquid::Block

    def initialize(tag_name, contain, tokens)
      super
    end

    def render(context)
      "<div class=\"container\">#{super}</div>"
    end
  end

  class RenderInner < Liquid::Block
    def initialize(tag_name, contain, tokens)
      super
    end

    def render(context)
      "<div class=\"inner\">#{super}</div>"
    end
  end
end

Liquid::Template.register_tag('container', Jekyll::RenderContainer)
Liquid::Template.register_tag('inner', Jekyll::RenderInner)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran into the same issue and apparently this is a [known bug](http://blog.slaks.net/2013-08-09/jekyll-tag-was-never-closed/). I tried your plugin and the liquid tag that you can't get to work above:

```
{% container %}
  {% inner %}
    Stuff Goes in here
  {% endinner %}
  {% inner %}
    Stuff Goes in here
  {% endinner %}
{% endcontainer %}
```

... and once I added the recommended fix (see below) to my `config.yml`, the code worked after that.

```
excerpt_separator: ""
```

Note, be sure to restart Jekyll serve after adding this bit to the config file.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for answering an almost year old question!